# I have 3 models, owners-dog grooming appointments-dogs, how can I do my relationship here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do a dog grooming website, using ruby / react-redux
So I draw it down, but I am not sure if I am doing it right? Can someone help please?

```
Owner - has many appointments 
Owner - has many dogs

Dog - has many appointments through owners
Dog - belongs_to owner

Appointment - has many dogs 
Appointment - belongs to owner
```

Is this right?

Comment: You need a joins table to have a has many through relationship btw owner and appointment. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Seems ok, depends on exact scenario and use case, You can always update the schema as needed in the development process, don't overthink and start building, that ebing said, i dont think this is a good question, if you have specific confusion or relation you can't figure out, please state that, otherwise i will vote to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have understood. Please correct me if i'm wrong.:

- Owner will have multiple dogs.
- Owner can book an appointment for a particular dog.
- Dog has only one owner (no co-owners)

As per the above statements, you can implement the following associations:

- Owner: has_many :appointments
- Owner: has_many :dogs
- Dog: belongs_to :owner
- Dog: has_many :appointments
- Appointment: belongs_to :owner
- Apointment: belongs_to_dog

Since dogs won't have multiple owners, there is no need of has_many through relation. Using the above associations, you can fetch the list of appoinments for owner as well as dog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding a second `Appointment: belongs_to :owner` foreign key column is not needed since you can get the owner through the dogs table. The big problem with this is that you would have to manually set one FK and handle edge cases where for example a dog changed owners.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set it up:

```
class Dog
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many :appointments
end

class Owner
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :appointments, through: :dogs
end

class Appointment
  belongs_to :dog # yes not owner
  has_one :owner, through: :dog
end
```

The reason why I choose `Appointment belongs_to :dog` is that it lets you handle the case where the owner has multiple dogs without ambiguity.